# I want to remove the secret information of a PrivateKey (sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl) from memory?

Tags: memory, cryptography, jvm, rsa, private-key

I have some Java code that generates an instance of a class that implements the interface java.security.PrivateKey (the actual object is an instance of sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl). The purpose of this code is to generate a PrivateKey, then split it into shares (divisions of the key) and then store the shares on smartcards. The shares part is working fine, the question I have is how to handle the PrivateKey once it is no longer needed.

There is a requirement that the PrivateKey information (which should be kept secret) should be removed from memory as soon as possible after it has been split into shares.

The interface PrivateKey extends the interface Destroyable, but I dont see the methods of Destroyable being implemented anywhere (it must be implemented somewhere in this hierarchy). But if I call destroy on the PrivateKey that I have (which is a RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl) then  it throws a javax.security.auth.DestroyFailedException.

The object that I have seems totally immutable, is there any way to overwrite the fields within the object? such as setting them to zero? or what approach should be followed for removing such secret immutable objects from memory? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, by using [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html).
I created a simple code you can use to destroy the key informations :

```
public static void destroyRSAKey(sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl key) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    destroyBigInteger(key.getModulus());
    destroyBigInteger(key.getPublicExponent());
    destroyBigInteger(key.getPrivateExponent());
    destroyBigInteger(key.getPrimeP());
    destroyBigInteger(key.getPrimeQ());
    destroyBigInteger(key.getPrimeExponentP());
    destroyBigInteger(key.getPrimeExponentQ());
    destroyBigInteger(key.getCrtCoefficient());
}
    
public static final void destroyBigInteger(java.math.BigInteger destroyThis) {
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field f = java.math.BigInteger.class.getDeclaredField("mag");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(destroyThis, new int[] { 0 });
        f.setAccessible(false);
        f = java.math.BigInteger.class.getDeclaredField("signum");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.setInt(destroyThis, 0);
        f.setAccessible(false);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
As documented above, `java.security.PrivateKey.destroy()` is not implemented in Java 8, which is a **Serious Security Gap** of the **Sun Java Runtime Environment** when deploying RSA algorithms.

Based on Doomny 58's solution, I got an actually running method `destroyPrivateRSAKey()` with proper content destruction; any error is mapped to `DestroyFailedException`, so when the call succeeds you may be sure, the private RSA parameters are destroyed.

```
/**
     * Destroy data of a BigInteger
     * 
     * @param destroyThis [in] BigIntegeer onject to destroy
     * @throws DestroyFailedException on any error
     */
    public static final void destroyBigInteger(java.math.BigInteger destroyThis) throws DestroyFailedException
    {
        if (destroyThis == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // Retrieve buffer field 'mag', overwrite with 0-s and set to {0}
            java.lang.reflect.Field f = java.math.BigInteger.class.getDeclaredField("mag");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            int[] mag = (int[]) f.get(destroyThis);
            if (mag != null)
            {
                java.util.Arrays.fill(mag, 0);
            }
            f.set(destroyThis, new int[] { 0 });
            f.setAccessible(false);

            // set field signum = 0
            f = java.math.BigInteger.class.getDeclaredField("signum");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.setInt(destroyThis, 0);
            f.setAccessible(false);
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new DestroyFailedException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get BigInteger member of an object with spec'd accesor method
     * @param o [in] The object 
     * @param accessor [in] Name of the accessor method
     * @return The BigInteger
     * @throws DestroyFailedException on any error
     */
    private static BigInteger accessBIF(Object o, String accessor) throws DestroyFailedException
    {
        try
        {
            Class<?> cls = o.getClass();
            Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod(accessor);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            BigInteger res = (BigInteger) m.invoke(o);
            m.setAccessible(false);
            return res;
        }
        catch (Throwable x)
        {
            x.printStackTrace();
            throw new DestroyFailedException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy BigInteger member
     * 
     * @param o        [in] Object with BigInteger
     * @param accessor [in] Member Accessor method
     * @throws DestroyFailedException
     */
    private static void destroyBIF(Object o, String accessor) throws DestroyFailedException
    {
        destroyBigInteger(accessBIF(o, accessor));
    }

    /**
     * Destroy Private RSA Key
     * 
     * @param key [in] A sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl
     * @throws DestroyFailedException
     */
    public static void destroyPrivateRSAKey(Object key) throws DestroyFailedException
    {
        destroyBIF(key, "getModulus");
        destroyBIF(key, "getPublicExponent");
        destroyBIF(key, "getPrivateExponent");
        destroyBIF(key, "getPrimeP");
        destroyBIF(key, "getPrimeQ");
        destroyBIF(key, "getPrimeExponentP");
        destroyBIF(key, "getPrimeExponentQ");
        destroyBIF(key, "getCrtCoefficient");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The same approach shown by Sam Ginrich can also be used to overwrite the memory of an elliptic curve private key (JDK15+). Due to the Jigsaw project / strong encapsulation of internals, you have to open (the crypto provider's module/package to your code using the JVM arg `--add-opens` - which of course carries its own set of disadvantages.

```java
    /**
     * Overwrites sensitive key material in memory. Object will be unusable after this call.
     * Requires JVM parameter to access private key internals:
     * --add-opens jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ed=[YOUR_MODULE]
     *
     * This is a workaround for missing destroy() implementation on EdDSAPrivateKeyImpl.
     */
    public static void wipeEdECPrivateKey(EdECPrivateKey privateKey) {
        try {

            // open private field for writing
            final Field field = privateKey.getClass().getDeclaredField("h");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            final byte[] h = (byte[]) field.get(privateKey);

            // overwrite key with zeroes
            Arrays.fill(h, (byte) 0);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

Edit: I opened a bug in OpenJDK, `EdECPrivateKey` actually inherits from `Destroyable`, but does not implement `destroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. The Java software implementation of key creation uses `BigInteger` which is indeed immutable. As you may have found out the `Destroyable.destroy` method is only implemented in few classes. As of Java 7 these were the directly implementing classes:

```
KerberosKey, KerberosTicket, KeyStore.PasswordProtection, X500PrivateCredential
```

I would guess that these classes do implement `Destroyable.destroy` but that all the others do not.

So the only thing you can do is to rely on the garbage collector and possibly the operating system to clean up and / or overwrite the `BigInteger` instances. Note that you would have the same issue when *using* the private key.

---

If you already have a SmartCard I would suggest using the smart cards to generate and split the keys. Generate the key internally, then encrypt the key with a symmetric AES key, split the AES key and transport the wrapped RSA key and the (2 remaining) key parts out of the smart card. [Usually XOR is used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing) instead of splitting the key literally.